# Setting up a locally shared folder as a repository

Tags: networking, repository, ftp

Recently I've setup a LAN connection with an old router. It doesn't have internet connectivity but is still useful as it is a 150 Mbps router and file sharing happens at record speeds. It also has better range than the current one with internet connectivity. And most of my work is done in my bedroom where the internet range of the other router doesn't span
I wanted to setup a folder shared over the network as a repository so i could load all the required deb and rpm files into it, then install it using apt or alien. This way i could access this repo from anywhere in my house from any computer and install apps. So, i need help with this. I tried setting up my phone as a ftp server and running the command sudo add-apt-repository ftp://192.168.29.145:2221 but it showed "Error: 'ftp://192.168.29.145:2221' invalid". I also tried the following-`sudo add-apt-repository 192.168.29.145`
`Error: '192.168.29.145' invalid`
`sudo add-apt-repository 192.168.29.145:2221`
`Error: '192.168.29.145:2221' invalid`
So, can someone please help me out? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: how does this relate to ask ubuntu?

Comment: See `man add-apt-repository` for how to add a URI.